# How to get information of installed application with the corresponding .apk file name

Tags: android

How to we find apk name corresponding to application installed on device. Assume that i have to all the root folders

Eg : If  there is some  xxxx.apk  and application name is Email.  Is there any way to know from device logs or device files that xxxx.apk is the apk name for Email application.?

Thanks,
Megha

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this class, the function `getInstalledApplications()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

It's just a filename; there's absolutely no correlation to the actual application or package name. I could get the APK for Facebook and rename it to GooglePlus.apk and it will still install Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that in /data/system/packages.xml in your android device, search for the "codePath" attribute.